# java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED after adding dependency for spring boot actuators

Tags: java, spring-boot-actuator

I have a java project in intellij-idea. I am using gradle to build it. Recently I have added dependency for spring boot actuators and since then I am getting this error on startup:

`*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844`

My application is still running after that but I would like to get rid of this error.

I was trying to find the answer on google but I was not able to find any.

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: [reference](https://jolorenz.wordpress.com/2014/08/09/how-to-solve-java-lang-instrument-assertion-failed-erroroutstanding-with-message-transform-method-call-failed-at-srcshareinstrumentjplisagent-c-line)

Answer (score 13):

Maybe not directly related to your problem, because mine had nothing to do with the `Spring Boot Actuator`, but maybe it might help someone else.

My problem occurred while I was testing my REST controllers. I do not provide DTOs but return my entities directly. I also have a bidirectional `One-To-Many` relationship between `Parent` and `Child`. The `GET` was producing `application/json` as `MediaType`.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Child> children;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Parent parent;

    ...
}
```

If I use my entities like this and was querying e.g. for a parent by id the JSON implementation was triggering a recursion between `Parent` and `Child`, but eventually returned with a value to my test.
To solve this problem I just added a `@JsonIgnore` to the parent field. Which in this case was sufficient for my requirements.

```
@Entity
public class Child {
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Parent parent;

    ...
}
```

Comment: this answer is brilliant one, thanks for the detailed reason explanation and solution suggestion, it works like charm

Comment: This was a life saver.. had same issue with circular dependancy for my Spring jpa entity ..after adding `@jsonIgnore` to my `@ManyToOne` field everything worked fine..