# Spring boot running on Azure container restarted with the error. Has anyone come across this before?

Tags: spring-boot, azure-container-apps

Spring boot running on Azure container restarted with the below error. Has anyone come across this before?

```
Log_s
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message can't create byte array at src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 836
```

Comment: out of memory error?

Comment: Did this error happen after a config change?

Comment: That is not mentioned in the question. It still can be OOM. Could try add more heap / container memory?

Comment: I couldn't find OOM error. But can see that % Of Max Heap Memory Used is 99.9%

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning/cause of \*\*\* java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED \*\*\*: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60526670/what-is-the-meaning-cause-of-java-lang-instrument-assertion-failed-er)

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering, `java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED: "!errorOutstanding" with message can't create byte array at src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 836`, typically indicates an issue within the Java Instrumentation process. This could be related to a problem with memory allocation for the creation of a byte array in the Java Instrumentation. It's not a common error and might be specific to your application's environment or its specific configuration on Azure. To address the `java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED` error in your Spring Boot application on Azure, follow these steps:

1. **Increase Heap Memory**: Adjust the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) settings to allocate more heap memory. This can be done by setting environment variables like `JAVA_OPTS` with values such as `-Xmx1024m` to increase the maximum heap size.
2. **Review Application Code**: Check for memory leaks or inefficient memory usage in your application code.
3. **Monitor Memory Usage**: Use tools like VisualVM or jConsole to monitor memory usage and garbage collection in real time.
4. **Optimize Garbage Collection**: Tweak garbage collection settings if necessary, using JVM options like `-XX:+UseG1GC`.
5. **Update Dependencies**: Ensure all Java dependencies, particularly those related to instrumentation, are up to date.

These steps should help in resolving memory-related issues in your application.

Reference Document:
[Similar Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671963/java-lang-instrument-assertion-failed-after-adding-dependency-for-spring-boot-ac)
[Similar Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60526670/what-is-the-meaning-cause-of-java-lang-instrument-assertion-failed-er)